# SQL primary key can accept '0'?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 / 2005

I am confused between Primary and Unique Key.

I am aware that Primary Key will not allow NULL, while Unique will accept NULL.
Also, a table can have 'n' number of unique keys ..!

Whether Primary Key will allow Zero ?

Comment: just an informative comment. this question is also applicable to `mySql`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Primary Key Can be Zero, but if you set Identity on the column it normally will start at 1 rather than Zero.

Comment: Primary Key will have Identity Column ..(Most likely or Most Scenario's) .. So Can i assume, if there is an identity Column we can start the seed / increment by 0. In order to start by Zero instead of 1, how to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to start the Increment at Zero anyway? But yes start the seed at Zero, and then increment by one so it would be IDENTITY(0,1)

Comment: I tested the scenario ..! If there is no Identity .., Primarykey will allow Zero ..!

Comment: Yeh that is correct. Like i said in my initial Answer stating that 'Primary Key Can be Zero'

Comment: This is an old question but my use case is using id 0 as a default for something not selected. If I manually enter a row with id 0 will this affect things negatively? It's a new table and there's no existing data. I just want to start at zero.

Answer (score 11):

A primary key can allow 0 depending of course on the datatype of the Primary key. An autogenerated PK (Identity) can start at 0 but that is not the default behavior, you will have to set it up to start at 0 (heck you can start with negative numbers if you want). For best results this should be done before you start entering data to the table.

What you cannot do is have multiple records with a 0 as the PK as that violates the uniqueness requirement of the PK.

If you have existing data and want a record that has a value of zero for a specific purpose (for instance we put in a user for our import process, so the insertedby field could show that the record came from an import), then what you probably want is to allow a manual insert into the identity field, so you can enter this one specific record at the value you want, then return to the usual setting. This is done this way:

```
set Identity_insert dbo.table1 ON
insert dbo.table1 (id, myfield)
Values (0, 'test')
set Identity_insert dbo.table1 OFF
```

Do not do this in application production code, this is a system admin type of task that should only be done occasionally for either the setting of a particular record outside the scope  of the normal data or to insert records transferring from another source (when you know their existing id values are currently unused). This should not be lightly used to get around the restrictions of an identity field. In particular it should never be used to fill in records where the identity skipped (due to a deletion or rollback) as this defeats the purpose of using an identity and can cause data integrity issues if proper PK/FK relationships were not set up.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and detailed explanation, also this is the only answer to show HOW to do the what the OP asked, while explaining WHY not to. Brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  NULL is the absence of a value.  `0` is a value.

Comment: Do primary key suppports ZERO ?

Comment: Yes.  The primary key supports ZERO

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a column with a default value of 0 as a Foreign Key. However, for the constraint to work, you would need to have a row in the source table with a value of 0 as well. ... You can insert the 0 primary id record in the main table.