# Why does querying a non-empty sequence whose only row has a PK of 0 sometimes throw?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sequence, primary-key

Consider this simple model:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<WTF> Wtf { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseSqlServer("Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database=DAFAQ0001;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    public class WTF
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None), Key] public long Aargh { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() => Aargh.ToString();
    }
}
```

Let us try to put a single row to the table thus created and then query this single row:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            db.Wtf.Add(new WTF { Aargh = 0 });
            db.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine(db.Wtf.Any()); // TRUE
            Console.WriteLine(db.Wtf.First().ToString()); // WORKS

            Console.WriteLine(db.Wtf.Max(wtf => wtf.Aargh)); // EXCEPTION
        }
    }
}
```

Yep - the last line produces a big, fat, ugly exception. Apparently, `sequence contains no elements` which seems weird because it DOES contain one element, the one I have just inserted! And the `Any` method itself confirms this. Even worse - querying this single element also works, as demostrated by calling `First`. It's just `Max` that fails, for reasons that I cannot understand.

```
True
0
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Max[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
   at ConsoleApp3.Program.Main() in C:\Users\m\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs:line 23

C:\Users\m\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ConsoleApp3.exe (process 11432) exited with code -532462766.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Oddly, inserting this single element with a PK of `1` instead of `0` seems to remedy the issue.

What's going on here? Is `0` an invalid value for a primary key? I Googled and found this SO answer: [SQL primary key can accept '0'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427142/sql-primary-key-can-accept-0) which says that `0` is a perfectly valid primary key value!

Could someone explain me why does the above code fail?

Edit: Responding to comments: If I click in VS the SQL Server Explorer window and view the code of this table this is what I get:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Wtf] (
    [Aargh] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Wtf] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Aargh] ASC)
);
```

Profiling this script in VS shows the following SQL is being executed to get the `Max`:

```sql
SELECT MAX([w].[Aargh]) FROM [Wtf] AS [w]
```

Executing this same SQL query in Sql Server Object Explorer in VS produces the following results:

```sql
(No column name)
0
```

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else, maybe related to EF. Could it be that you should be using MaxOrDefault() instead of simply calling the MAX on the val? 

You can use a 0 as a PK value having the long type for that column with no problems. 
You can check the following [demo](https://rextester.com/BSI95358).

Comment: @RBarryYoung Question updated to provide the information you requested.

Comment: I think you'll find it's an EF limitation... In [Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations), Key types and values says, *Key properties must always have a non-default value when adding a new entity to the context, but some types will be generated by the database.* In other words you can't use `0` as a Key value because it's the default value for `long`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Ugh this is a gotcha... Well thank you for pointing this out to me

Comment: WHich EF version is this?

Comment: @GertArnold `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.0" />`; `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />`; `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.0">` - does this answer your question?

Comment: Well, clearly a bug. Maybe you could report it on their github site.